# How to programatically click on a button from Whatsapp from a different app?

Tags: android, mobile, onclick, whatsapp

I want to be able to call the onClick of a WhatsApp button from my app.
i.e onClick() method from my app will open WhatsApp and click on a view/ button. 
Has anyone attempted this before?

Thank you.

Comment: This is not possible

Comment: Fortunately, that is not generally possible, for obvious security reasons. The primary practical option is an accessibility service, and [Google is banning apps from the Play Store that use an accessibility service for non-accessibility purposes](https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2017/11/google-cracks-down-on-power-user-apps-that-use-androids-accessibility-api/).

Comment: Hi guys. Thank you for your comment. I'm not planing to put the app in the play store. Could you share an example on how I could achieve this with an accessibility service? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have contacted WhatsApp to see if there is any API(or something) that will allow me to do this and they said it's not possible.